# Mysql with index

Tags: mysql, index, select

I have this following sentence:

```
SELECT Day(C.DataCadastro) AS Dia, 
       Month(C.DataCadastro) AS Mes, 
       Year(C.DataCadastro) AS Ano, 
       COUNT(I.Plano) AS Total 
FROM clientes AS C 
   JOIN clube_infoclientes AS I ON C.CodUsuario = I.ClienteID 
WHERE ((I.Plano = 1) AND (C.Ativo = 1)) 
GROUP BY Mes 
ORDER BY Dia, Mes, Ano
```

The name of index is: Plan. sentence of creating is
        `CREATE INDEX Plan ON clube_infoclientes (Plano(2));`

But I can't use INDEX here.. 
My question is how I do implement INDEX on the select above

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Oh sorry. My question is how I do implement INDEX on the select above?

Comment: What do you mean with "implement index"? That doesn't make sense. Indexes are created (using a `create index` like the one you have) - they are not "implemented".

Comment: But because when I run the sentence I get the same result when I had not?

Comment: You don't "use" indexes. The optimizer chooses them automatically if it makes sense. And they don't change the result of a query, they improve the speed, that's all.

Comment: Besides the comments by @a_horse_with_no_name, the query doesn't make much sense. You group by `MONTH(C.DataCadastro)`, yet you still want to show in the results, the `DAY(C.DataCadastro)`. What if there are more than 1 rows in the same month, but with different date?

Comment: This is the problem, (I did this database!), but if I remove (GROUP BY), My query never stop! (the database have 120.000.00 registers).

Comment: You didn't answer the question. If there are 2 or more rows in the same month with different dates, which date should it be shown? (I assume you want in the results, 1 row per month)

Comment: Yes this is it!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name actually you can "hint" the MySQL optimizer with FORCE INDEX(index_name) or IGNORE INDEX(index_name).. see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html

Comment: Well Day and YEAR output can contain random (read wrong data) that doens't match your GROUP BY Mes record... because MySQL has extended the use off GROUP BY

Comment: @BrunoCasali Consider to [edit](http://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/52841/edit) your question and include some sample data and the desired output from the query based on that sample data. That can clarify your question and help you get your answer.

Comment: Thanks @Peterm  but I resolved my question!, Thanks to all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem's it:

I was using the indexes  with two columns that are not important to me!
I Resolve using indexes on the following columns: C.CodUsuario = I.ClienteID

Thanks to all! ;D